# In Python, what do %25s, %28s, %15s, %3s etc mean?

Tags: python, string, syntax, string-formatting

I've heard of string formatting, but what the heck are these %25s, %28s, %15s, %3s in this snippet:

```py
return "Scan Name: %25s\nTarget(s): %25s\nPolicy: %28s\n\nRisk Summary\n%s\n%15s %3s\n%15s %3s\n%15s %3s\n\n%15s %3s" % ( report, prefs['TARGET'], policy,'-'*36,'High', severity['3'], 'Medium', severity['2'], 'Low', severity['1'], 'Open Ports', severity['0'])
```

Comment: that's actually not the same question; you don't have named keys in your format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [format specification](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

In your case, `%25s` will format the appropriate value as a string with a minimum field width of 25 characters, for example.