# How to format strings and hexadecimals in Scriban

Tags: c#, templates, scriban

I am writing C# solution that generates a C++ file base on some configuration. For this i am using Scriban as a template engine. I saw the following statement before in Jinja2:

```
uint16_t {{"%25s"|format(device.name)}} = {{"0x%08x"|format(device.address)}};
```

device.name is a string and device.address contain Hexadecimal value (0x50060800).

I tried this:

```
uint16_t {{device.name | object.format "%25s"}} = {{device.address | math.format "0x%08x"}};
```

And i received the following error:

```
<input>(15,50) : error : Unexpected `RNG`. Must be a formattable object
<input>(15,71) : error : Unexpected `0x50060800`. Must be a formattable object
```

This is the result I was expecting:

```
uint16_t RNG = 0x50060800;
```

How can I implement the above statement in Scriban?

Comment: Could you add the C# code around the template that provides the variables? As it looks now you don't need to format anything since the values `RNG` and `0x50060800` are already in the expected form (especially the string `RNG`, what is the goal of the format string `%25s` there?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered [in your GitHub issue](https://github.com/scriban/scriban/issues/478).  I'll paste here for posterity

Keep in mind:

- Jinja is written for Python.  So, it uses Python conventions for things like format strings.
- Scriban is written in C# - it uses C# conventions for format strings.

Based on [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049610/in-python-what-do-25s-28s-15s-3s-etc-mean), it seems that by using `"%25s"`, you are attempting to pad the width of `device.name` to 25 characters.  The way to do that in *Scriban* is using the `string.pad_right` (or `string.pad_left`) function.

Additionally, your hex format string is incorrect ([see the C# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#hexadecimal-format-specifier-x) on the `X` specifier for numeric format strings)

Putting all that together:

```
uint16_t {{device.name | string.pad_right 25 }} = 0x{{device.address | math.format "X8"}};
```

Note, however, the numeric format strings only work on numeric types.  So, if the `device.address` property is a `string` in decimal representation (i.e., `"1342572544"`), you first must convert it to a number, like so:

```
0x{{device.address | string.to_int | math.format "X8"}};
```

If the `device.address` property is a `string` in *hexadecimal* representation, it gets a bit tricker.  I don't see a built-in function to convert that for you.  So, you'll have to make your own.  [See an example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YacGg8)

Comment: Thank you, I tried your example and it works.